# Cloned shared_ptr and leaks in destructors

Tags: c++

I use shared_ptr to handle pointers like this in my program.

```
struct D
{
    D() { std::cout << "D ctor\n"; }
    ~D() { std::cout << "D dtor\n"; }
};
struct CC
{
private:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<D>> pDs;
    static std::shared_ptr<CC>  pC;
    CC() { std::cout << "C ctor\n"; };
public:
    static std::shared_ptr<CC> GetInstance()
    {
        if (nullptr == pC)
        {
            pC = std::shared_ptr<CC>(new CC);
            return pC;
        }
        return pC;
    }
    void Save(std::shared_ptr<D> d)
    {
        pDs.emplace_back(d);
        std::cout << "saved b\n";
    }
    void Delete(int i)
    {
        pDs.erase(pDs.begin() + i);
    }
    int Size() { return pDs.size(); }
    ~CC() { std::cout << "C dtor\n"; }
};
std::shared_ptr<CC> CC::pC(nullptr);
struct Caller
{
    void Init()
    {
        std::shared_ptr<D> d = std::shared_ptr<D>(new D());
        CC::GetInstance()->Save(d);
    }
    int Size() 
    {
        return CC::GetInstance()->Size();
    }
};
struct Deletor
{
    void Delete(int i) 
    {
        CC::GetInstance()->Delete(i);
    }
};
```

Using this in a console application, there is no error.
My question is,

if I save or clone many instances of shared_ptr in 2 or more different map/vector objects (shared_ptr are used as their values) as shown above, and at some point I would want to remove 1 or more instances of them (via e.g `erase(key/iterator)`) of one object, how can I manipulate their twins that are stored in other objects?

For example,

```
MAP_A = MAP_B = {key,shared_ptr}
MAP_A.erase(key_i);
//what should I do with MAP_B(key_i)?
```

Comment: I might not understand the question correctly, but you shouldn't do that. The point of `shared_ptr` is to have a pointer, that can exist in many places and none of its users have to care about it's ownership or when to delete it. If you reset this pointer in one place and won't notify other users, program might crash.

Comment: I think you should include more detail on what you want to do. By the way, instead of `std::shared_ptr<T>(new T())`, almost always a better choice is `std::make_shared<T>()`.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen, how can I notify other users if I remove one shared pointer in one user? I try to update them and my application crashes in the destructor of the shared object.

Comment: Well, as I mentioned, you shouldn't. That would be a whole new unnecessary system. Please provide us with [mcve], as we don't know how are these classes used and destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

> how can I manipulate their twins that are stored in other objects?

No need. That's the entire point for having a `shared_ptr`.

As per [std::shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr):

> `std::shared_ptr` is a smart pointer that retains **shared ownership
>   of an object** through a pointer. Several shared_ptr objects may own
>   the same object.

It has a reference counting mechanism that tracks how many pointers are sharing the "shared" object.

> leaks in destructors

Once reference count is zero that's the time the shared object is freed.
This guarantees that there will be at most no leaks.

Comment: I have a corruption of heap in the called destructor of the object shared when I try to remove the instance of the one after its twin is deleted in another.
exception is thrown in this function (`free_base.cpp`)
`extern "C" void __cdecl _free_base(void* const block)` 
at HeapFree

Comment: Also, even when I don't do anything to it, I still get the same exception if I close my application window.

Comment: @OstrichGroomer The problem could be anywhere. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: if you would do something like
`auto str = std::make_shared<wstring>();
std::shared_ptr<wstring> other(str.get());`
you would have 2 separate reference counter for the same object thus you would have double frees.